# How to post a request in SHARECHAT APP in POSTMAN API

Tags: python, api, rest, postman

Right now I am developing a small python app for posting posts in Apps. I have searched for an example and documentation on SHARE CHAT APP. They have just given only just API TOKEN and some JSON format details. can you guys help me to sort out the problem?

[image: Documentation Image of Sharechat Dashboard]

Can you guys help me to solve this problem.

Posting some example API POST Request will be more helpful...

Rightnow i'm using POSTMAN API Services

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "status": "Fail",
    "msg": "\"token\" is required"
}
```

this is error response when i post a request in postman.

How to do a post request in POSTMAN API for Sharechat APP. Posting some example of similar API request will be helpful.

Comment: Any update to this problem, Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to import
then Select Raw Text and paste

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://apis.sharechat.com/developerApis/v1.0.0/getTrendingTags?language=Gujarati' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer "token"'
```

then it will look like this

[image]

here this the final results

[image]

then replace "token" with your token

and done.

Comment: then you can easily change language..etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use in python

```
import requests
url = "https://apis.sharechat.com/developerApis/v1.0.0/getTrendingTags?language=Hindi"

headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhYmt1Y2hneWFuIiwiYWNjb3VudElkIjoiMjkwNzAiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIzMjQ0MTM3NjUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTMxMjU2NTR9.5cmK767pKLVDZI2Dlv7EKekZ2CdAE5Nmt9mhAvriQfc'}
resp = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data = resp.json()
print(data)
```

make sure to do
chcp 65001 first otherwise it will give error

Comment: don't worry this token is reset